# How to convert a milliseconds into the normal time inside the list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, date, datetime

I'm parcing a web-site on Python 3.6.2

I got a long list *(it has about 17000 symbols)*:

```
[[1194570000000, 1806.22], [1194829200000, 1792.02], [1194915600000, 1777.35], [1195002000000, 1783.27], [1195088400000, 1782.55], [1195174800000, 1760.89], [1195434000000, 1751.49], [1195520400000, 1747.99], [1195606800000, 1741.47], [1195693200000, 1726.78], [1195779600000, 1730.69], [1196038800000, 1750.07], [1196125200000, 1738.24], [1196211600000, 1730.1], [1196298000000, 1744.72], [1196384400000, 1759.95], [1196643600000, 1759.74], [1196730000000, 1754.45], [1196816400000, 1772.8], [1196902800000, 1786.09], [1196989200000, 1790.25], [1197248400000, 1796.63], [1197334800000, 1815.07], [1197421200000, 1818.52], [1197507600000, 1816.8], [1197594000000, 1796.78], [1197853200000, 1772.76], [1197939600000, 1789.9], [1198026000000, 1781.98], [1198112400000, 1794.38], [1198198800000, 1797.66], [1198458000000, 1807.15], [1198544400000, 1801.53], [1198630800000, 1799.07], [1198717200000, 1800.78], [1198803600000, 1800.3], [1198890000000, 1800.23], [1199926800000, 1825.09], [1200013200000, 1827.88], [1200272400000, 1828.87], [1200358800000, 1832.82], [1200445200000, 1788.15], [1200531600000, 1746.4], [1200618000000, 1729.26], [1200877200000, 1657.58], [1200963600000, 1606.25], [1201050000000, 1603.64], [1201136400000, 1621.03], [1201222800000, 1657.67], [1201482000000, 1628.03], [1201568400000, 1629.02], [1201654800000, 1617.45], [1201741200000, 1585.1], [1201827600000, 1615.29], [1202086800000, 1666.69], [1202173200000, 1673.41], [1202259600000, 1633.71], [1202346000000, 1625.94], [1202432400000, 1624.1], [1202691600000, 1638.08], [1202778000000, 1701.16], [1202864400000, 1721.58], [1202950800000, 1756.86], [1203037200000, 1732.13], [1203296400000, 1751.02], [1203382800000, 1760.49], [1203469200000, 1755.08], [1203555600000, 1780.1], [1203642000000, 1778.15], [1203987600000, 1786.42], [1204074000000, 1777.88], [1204160400000, 1767.45], [1204246800000, 1764.72], [1204506000000, 1734.83], [1204592400000, 1739.02], [1204678800000, 1730.82], [1204765200000, 1738.13], [1204851600000, 1710.22], [1205197200000, 1714.67], [1205283600000, 1748.51], [1205370000000, 1727.69], [1205456400000, 1735.35], [1205715600000, 1681.17], [1205802000000, 1680.49], [1205888400000, 1687.95], [1205974800000, 1658.55], [1206061200000, 1669.67], [1206320400000, 1666.83], [1206406800000, 1682.01], [1206493200000, 1673.85], [1206579600000, 1692.85], [1206666000000, 1711.2], [1206921600000, 1732.77], [1207008000000, 1747.96], [1207094400000, 1757.32], [1207180800000, 1754.46], [1207267200000, 1745.45], [1207526400000, 1764.22], [1207612800000, 1758.4], [1207699200000, 1770.59], [1207785600000, 1776.8], [1207872000000, 1775.61], [1208131200000, 1759.18], [1208217600000, 1782.33], [1208304000000, 1803.16], [1208390400000, 1819.44], [1208476800000, 1825.26], [1208736000000, 1834.73], [1208822400000, 1819.78], [1208908800000, 1818.49], [1208995200000, 1804.03], [1209081600000, 1797.37], [1209340800000, 1819.62], [1209427200000, 1816.22], [1209513600000, 1788.91], [1209859200000, 1818.08], [1209945600000, 1825.41], [1210032000000, 1835.86], [1210118400000, 1860.42], [1210204800000, 1890.98], [1210550400000, 1912.79], [1210636800000, 1921.4], [1210723200000, 1930.14], [1210809600000, 1961.11], [1210896000000, 1976.18], [1211155200000, 1982.32], [1211241600000, 1962.19], [1211328000000, 1971.47], [1211414400000, 1958.48], [1211500800000, 1937.04], [1211760000000, 1924.79], [1211846400000, 1920.34], [1211932800000, 1910.95], [1212019200000, 1937.63], [1212105600000, 1939.91], [1212364800000, 1954.14], [1212451200000, 1943.88], [1212537600000, 1917.49], [1212624000000, 1908.67], [1212710400000, 1920.71], [1212796800000, 1888.57], [1212969600000, 1902.74], [1213056000000, 1893.78], [1213142400000, 1910.03], [1213574400000, 1934.58], [1213660800000, 1954.97], [1213747200000, 1971.5], [1213833600000, 1967.82], [1213920000000, 1958.94], [1214179200000, 1925.44], [1214265600000, 1897.82], [1214352000000, 1898.14], [1214438400000, 1888.13], [1214524800000, 1853.59], [1214784000000, 1874.87], [1214870400000, 1843.88], [1214956800000, 1836.45], [1215043200000, 1801.29], [1215129600000, 1799.02], [1215388800000, 1801.73], [1215475200000, 1778.26], [1215561600000, 1782.45], [1215648000000, 1781.25], [1215734400000, 1768.2], [1215993600000, 1764.23], [1216080000000, 1737.92], [1216166400000, 1725.59], [1216252800000, 1752.41], [1216339200000, 1738.93], [1216598400000, 1718.19], [1216684800000, 1712.45], [1216771200000, 1718.95], [1216857600000, 1686.71], [1216944000000, 1587.53], [1217203200000, 1581.52], [1217289600000, 1524.75], [1217376000000, 1557.89], [1217462400000, 1581.82], [1217548800000, 1580.59], [1217808000000, 1559.64], [1217894400000, 1513.67], [1217980800000, 1503.23], [1218067200000, 1527.85], [1218153600000, 1482.64], [1218412800000, 1445.45], [1218499200000, 1508.53], [1218585600000, 1514.26], [1218672000000, 1539.56], [1218758400000, 1535.05], [1219017600000, 1535.95], [1219104000000, 1477.17], [1219276800000, 1483.31], [1219363200000, 1476.09], [1219622400000, 1442.8], [1219708800000, 1364.55], [1219795200000, 1367.89], [1219881600000, 1391.75], [1219968000000, 1404.44], [1220227200000, 1426.43], [1220313600000, 1418.14], [1220400000000, 1389.37], [1220486400000, 1360.89], [1220572800000, 1255.55], [1220832000000, 1293.47], [1220918400000, 1239.64], [1221004800000, 1132.71], [1221091200000, 1138.64], [1221177600000, 1157.26], [1221436800000, 1125.8], [1221523200000, 1023.4], [1221609600000, 964.38], [1221696000000, 963.58], [1221782400000, 1096.9], [1222041600000, 1158.72], [1222128000000, 1126.96], [1222214400000, 1138.86], [1222300800000, 1107.07], [1222387200000, 1093.35], [1222646400000, 1056.35], [1222732800000, 994.01], [1222819200000, 1025.51], [1222905600000, 997.97], [1222992000000, 916.35], [1223251200000, 808.1], [1223337600000, 757.5], [1223424000000, 682.82], [1223510400000, 694.25], [1223596800000, 694.19], [1223856000000, 672.24], [1223942400000, 718.12], [1224028800000, 682.73], [1224115200000, 614.08], [1224201600000, 573.74], [1224460800000, 578.35], [1224547200000, 602.25], [1224633600000, 584.62], [1224720000000, 563.86], [1224806400000, 514.53], [1225069200000, 514.39], [1225155600000, 488.76], [1225242000000, 529.27], [1225328400000, 611.05], [1225414800000, 625.17], [1225501200000, 689.32], [1225846800000, 732.17], [1225933200000, 650.25], [1226019600000, 640.83], [1226278800000, 679.3], [1226365200000, 589.93], [1226451600000, 589.87], [1226538000000, 517.05], [1226624400000, 542.3], [1226883600000, 501.9], [1226970000000, 479.59], [1227056400000, 478.47], [1227142800000, 450.07], [1227229200000, 457.15], [1227488400000, 478.68], [1227574800000, 517.51], [1227661200000, 505.31], [1227747600000, 528.05], [1227834000000, 534.75], [1228093200000, 536.86], [1228179600000, 510.96], [1228266000000, 516.41], [1228352400000, 519.82], [1228438800000, 509.61], [1228698000000, 542.01], [1228784400000, 559.07], [1228870800000, 571.89], [1228957200000, 575.07], [1229043600000, 547.36], [1229302800000, 575.82], [1229389200000, 571.53], [1229475600000, 574.57], [1229562000000, 552.97], [1229648400000, 534.69], [1229907600000, 568.61], [1229994000000, 580.45], [1230080400000, 586.15], [1230166800000, 566.55], [1230253200000, 557.38], [1230512400000, 555.76], [1230598800000, 547.45], [1230685200000, 548.16], [1231635600000, 563.58], [1231722000000, 575.88], [1231808400000, 572.75], [1231894800000, 576.31], [1231981200000, 549.98], [1232067600000, 553.97], [1232326800000, 530.95], [1232413200000, 512.12], [1232499600000, 508.34], [1232586000000, 514.01], [1232672400000, 489.04], [1232931600000, 509.06], [1233018000000, 528.42], [1233104400000, 539.64], [1233190800000, 546.1], [1233277200000, 556.09], [1233536400000, 555.23], [1233622800000, 565.5], [1233709200000, 576.94], [1233795600000, 583.89], [1233882000000, 606.37], [1234141200000, 650.84], [1234227600000, 670.48], [1234314000000, 665.39], [1234400400000, 657.63], [1234486800000, 660.24], [1234746000000, 663.05], [1234832400000, 637.9], [1234918800000, 600.87], [1235005200000, 621.45], [1235091600000, 607.74], [1235437200000, 597.27], [1235523600000, 620.61], [1235610000000, 631.12], [1235696400000, 632.53], [1235955600000, 616.06], [1236042000000, 614.71], [1236128400000, 634.31], [1236214800000, 633.7], [1236301200000, 636.42], [1236646800000, 676.8], [1236733200000, 687.33], [1236819600000, 664.34], [1236906000000, 677.91], [1237165200000, 673.76], [1237251600000, 680.96], [1237338000000, 678.9], [1237424400000, 690.34], [1237510800000, 713.94], [1237770000000, 765.98], [1237856400000, 761.21], [1237942800000, 792.88], [1238029200000, 815.54], [1238115600000, 817.43], [1238371200000, 757.88], [1238457600000, 768.05], [1238544000000, 771.56], [1238630400000, 799.54], [1238716800000, 806.71], [1238976000000, 826.06], [1239062400000, 805.96], [1239148800000, 816.81], [1239235200000, 867.51], [1239321600000, 897.57], [1239580800000, 905.51], [1239667200000, 943.68], [1239753600000, 947.12], [1239840000000, 952.44], [1239926400000, 974.06], [1240185600000, 950.03], [1240272000000, 921.33], [1240358400000, 938.02], [1240444800000, 972.55], [1240531200000, 987.71], [1240790400000, 969.15], [1240876800000, 929.82], [1240963200000, 975.75], [1241049600000, 1009.64], [1241395200000, 1042.23], [1241481600000, 1069.43], [1241568000000, 1084.97], [1241654400000, 1163.66], [1241740800000, 1161.41], [1242086400000, 1181.97], [1242172800000, 1176.05], [1242259200000, 1108.11], [1242345600000, 1137.12], [1242604800000, 1121.17], [1242691200000, 1151.36], [1242777600000, 1171.26], [1242864000000, 1164.11], [1242950400000, 1162.57], [1243209600000, 1165.35], [1243296000000, 1142.74], [1243382400000, 1171.37], [1243468800000, 1172.33], [1243555200000, 1203.54], [1243814400000, 1262.5], [1243900800000, 1289.68], [1243987200000, 1268.4], [1244073600000, 1250.81], [1244160000000, 1285.42], [1244419200000, 1262.42], [1244505600000, 1277.5], [1244592000000, 1304.35], [1244678400000, 1300.95], [1245024000000, 1264.32], [1245110400000, 1255.02], [1245196800000, 1233], [1245283200000, 1183.33], [1245369600000, 1192.41], [1245628800000, 1142.32], [1245715200000, 1069.01], [1245801600000, 1118.55], [1245888000000, 1127.34], [1245974400000, 1141.99], [1246233600000, 1124.32], [1246320000000, 1144.29], [1246406400000, 1128.87], [1246492800000, 1122.6], [1246579200000, 1106.46], [1246838400000, 1076.98], [1246924800000, 1076.09], [1247011200000, 1042.85], [1247097600000, 1041.93], [1247184000000, 1010.26], [1247443200000, 997.8], [1247529600000, 1037.49], [1247616000000, 1044.34], [1247702400000, 1050.26], [1247788800000, 1063.75], [1248048000000, 1089.15], [1248134400000, 1101.04], [1248220800000, 1093.33], [1248307200000, 1107.34], [1248393600000, 1145.76], [1248652800000, 1183.04], [1248739200000, 1172.51], [1248825600000, 1152.45], [1248912000000, 1185.01], [1248998400000, 1203.98], [1249257600000, 1249.48], [1249344000000, 1235.59], [1249430400000, 1251.26], [1249516800000, 1252.76], [1249603200000, 1245.49], [1249862400000, 1263.41], [1249948800000, 1250.72], [1250035200000, 1227.87], [1250121600000, 1271.28], [1250208000000, 1269.32], [1250467200000, 1216.47], [1250553600000, 1234.36], [1250640000000, 1222.69], [1250726400000, 1239.34], [1250812800000, 1270.14], [1251072000000, 1309.02], [1251158400000, 1311.1], [1251244800000, 1319.67], [1251331200000, 1322.77], [1251417600000, 1346.3], [1251676800000, 1344.57], [1251763200000, 1372.85], [1251849600000, 1367.47], [1251936000000, 1384.82], [1252022400000, 1381], [1252281600000, 1399.53], [1252368000000, 1451.52], [1252454400000, 1486.98], [1252540800000, 1516.02], [1252627200000, 1535.25], [1252886400000, 1518.48], [1252972800000, 1550.23], [1253059200000, 1577.56], [1253145600000, 1616.07], [1253232000000, 1643.75], [1253491200000, 1620.48], [1253577600000, 1653.28], [1253664000000, 1652.49], [1253750400000, 1632.9], [1253836800000, 1643.01], [1254096000000, 1657.87], [1254182400000, 1690.57], [1254268800000, 1711.31], [1254355200000, 1726.62], [1254441600000, 1668.86], [1254700800000, 1698.15], [1254787200000, 1723.63], [1254873600000, 1796.48], [1254960000000, 1855.47], [1255046400000, 1866.12], [1255305600000, 1909.47], [1255392000000, 1909.81], [1255478400000, 1947.76], [1255564800000, 1947.59], [1255651200000, 1929.36], [1255910400000, 1947.13], [1255996800000, 1977.64], [1256083200000, 1975.57], [1256169600000, 1962.69], [1256256000000, 2009.06], [1256518800000, 2038.76], [1256605200000, 1973.44], [1256691600000, 1900.16], [1256778000000, 1865.5], [1256864400000, 1901.15], [1257123600000, 1867.59], [1257210000000, 1840.98], [1257382800000, 1864.77], [1257469200000, 1880.08], [1257728400000, 1920.11], [1257814800000, 1948.4], [1257901200000, 1962.72], [1257987600000, 1922.58], [1258074000000, 1902.03], [1258333200000, 1949.41], [1258419600000, 1943.86], [1258506000000, 1972.27], [1258592400000, 1945.69], [1258678800000, 1930.92], [1258938000000, 1952.74], [1259024400000, 1928.06], [1259110800000, 1933.98], [1259197200000, 1864.53], [1259283600000, 1820.72], [1259542800000, 1869.23], [1259629200000, 1909.74], [1259715600000, 1914.24], [1259802000000, 1928.28], [1259888400000, 1907.94], [1260147600000, 1908.85], [1260234000000, 1893.61], [1260320400000, 1881.92], [1260406800000, 1876.59], [1260493200000, 1888.93], [1260752400000, 1894.9], [1260838800000, 1915.16], [1260925200000, 1938.58], [1261011600000, 1945.07], [1261098000000, 1962.33], [1261357200000, 1965.04], [1261443600000, 1961.31], [1261530000000, 1953.76], [1261616400000, 1937.68], [1261702800000, 1927.8], [1261962000000, 1940.8], [1262048400000, 1939.3], [1262134800000, 1944.21], [1262221200000, 1956.6], [1263171600000, 2065.07], [1263258000000, 2064.64], [1263344400000, 2090.27], [1263430800000, 2128.52], [1263517200000, 2176.48], [1263776400000, 2194.19], [1263862800000, 2205.26], [1263949200000, 2268.81], [1264035600000, 2294.71], [1264122000000, 2199.22], [1264381200000, 2193.58], [1264467600000, 2144.89], [1264554000000, 2149.68], [1264640400000, 2218.12], [1264726800000, 2237.17], [1264986000000, 2229.98], [1265072400000, 2270.82], [1265158800000, 2334.71], [1265245200000, 2293.67], [1265331600000, 2170.48], [1265590800000, 2154.39], [1265677200000, 2140.96], [1265763600000, 2160.78], [1265850000000, 2157.81], [1265936400000, 2152.04], [1266195600000, 2166.07], [1266282000000, 2208.66], [1266368400000, 2241.27], [1266454800000, 2204.89], [1266541200000, 2194.01], [1266973200000, 2205.58], [1267059600000, 2195.12], [1267146000000, 2206.47], [1267232400000, 2241.65], [1267405200000, 2254.96], [1267491600000, 2259.17], [1267578000000, 2269.09], [1267664400000, 2290.47], [1267750800000, 2316.19], [1268096400000, 2312.49], [1268182800000, 2316.02], [1268269200000, 2300.43], [1268355600000, 2323.75], [1268614800000, 2333.29], [1268701200000, 2339.15], [1268787600000, 2366.15], [1268874000000, 2373.97], [1268960400000, 2367.54], [1269219600000, 2352.68], [1269306000000, 2371.24], [1269392400000, 2359.14], [1269478800000, 2365.72], [1269565200000, 2416.75], [1269820800000, 2421.75], [1269907200000, 2453.62], [1269993600000, 2485.89], [1270080000000, 2520.2], [1270166400000, 2509.26], [1270425600000, 2527.51], [1270512000000, 2549.75], [1270598400000, 2510.39], [1270684800000, 2495.96], [1270771200000, 2537.35], [1271030400000, 2556.07], [1271116800000, 2599.57], [1271203200000, 2646.47], [1271289600000, 2646.61], [1271376000000, 2592.88], [1271635200000, 2500.75], [1271721600000, 2540.25], [1271808000000, 2538.07], [1271894400000, 2509.43], [1271980800000, 2500.58], [1272240000000, 2562.76], [1272326400000, 2519.97], [1272412800000, 2457.82], [1272499200000, 2491.67], [1272585600000, 2501.05], [1272931200000, 2429.29], [1273017600000, 2362.58], [1273104000000, 2322.6], [1273190400000, 2204.22], [1273536000000, 2208.73], [1273622400000, 2243.5], [1273708800000, 2275.73], [1273795200000, 2209.73], [1274054400000, 2196.03], [1274140800000, 2239.5], [1274227200000, 2172.53], [1274313600000, 2113.25], [1274400000000, 2041.37], [1274659200000, 2096.79], [1274745600000, 2019.49], [1274832000000, 2045.77], [1274918400000, 2103.37], [1275004800000, 2117.9], [1275264000000, 2138.24], [1275350400000, 2120.55], [1275436800000, 2137.98], [1275523200000, 2200.41], [1275609600000, 2183.65], [1275868800000, 2120.63], [1275955200000, 2132.57], [1276041600000, 2135.47], [1276128000000, 2138.14], [1276214400000, 2139.16], [1276560000000, 2154.37], [1276646400000, 2166.77], [1276732800000, 2170.14], [1276819200000, 2157], [1277078400000, 2203.37], [1277164800000, 2188.95], [1277251200000, 2177.6], [1277337600000, 2152.36], [1277424000000, 2127.99], [1277683200000, 2136.44], [1277769600000, 2079.88], [1277856000000, 2041.62], [1277942400000, 1996.26], [1278028800000, 1983.89], [1278288000000, 1996.61], [1278374400000, 2029.39], [1278460800000, 2033.7], [1278547200000, 2090.78], [1278633600000, 2071.53], [1278892800000, 2088.88], [1278979200000, 2116.48], [1279065600000, 2115.64], [1279152000000, 2114.95], [1279238400000, 2091.12], [1279497600000, 2087.68], [1279584000000, 2079.61], [1279670400000, 2105.69], [1279756800000, 2113.61], [1279843200000, 2146.42], [1280102400000, 2167.61], [1280188800000, 2175.95], [1280275200000, 2181.87], [1280361600000, 2206.88], [1280448000000, 2199.06], [1280707200000, 2249.88], [1280793600000, 2238.43], [1280880000000, 2244.51], [1280966400000, 2247.07], [1281052800000, 2238.67], [1281312000000, 2260.88], [1281398400000, 2235.64], [1281484800000, 2206.03], [1281571200000, 2183.63], [1281657600000, 2182.92], [1281916800000, 2174.21], [1282003200000, 2209.7], [1282089600000, 2213.49], [1282176000000, 2219.71], [1282262400000, 2203.89], [1282521600000, 2211.16], [1282608000000, 2183.58], [1282694400000, 2185.76], [1282780800000, 2200.34], [1282867200000, 2201.8], [1283126400000, 2229.02], [1283212800000, 2205.47], [1283299200000, 2235.49], [1283385600000, 2265.73], [1283472000000, 2272.88], [1283731200000, 2307.1], [1283817600000, 2289.12], [1283904000000, 2316], [1283990400000, 2336.63], [1284076800000, 2353.65], [1284336000000, 2364.86], [1284422400000, 2345.28], [1284508800000, 2330.23], [1284595200000, 2332.73], [1284681600000, 2329.07], [1284940800000, 2311.08], [1285027200000, 2340.75], [1285113600000, 2322.33], [1285200000000, 2318.23], [1285286400000, 2314.83], [1285545600000, 2322.81], [1285632000000, 2273.99], [1285718400000, 2291.21], [1285804800000, 2299.94], [1285891200000, 2324.88], [1286150400000, 2345.1], [1286236800000, 2349.47], [1286323200000, 2362.85], [1286409600000, 2343.36], [1286496000000, 2324.29], [1286755200000, 2350.54], [1286841600000, 2356.69], [1286928000000, 2379.54], [1287014400000, 2385.66], [1287100800000, 2391.12], [1287360000000, 2391.33], [1287446400000, 2388.31], [1287532800000, 2383.03], [1287619200000, 2368.92], [1287705600000, 2365.76], [1287964800000, 2377.83], [1288051200000, 2374.57], [1288137600000, 2371.17], [1288224000000, 2368.49], [1288310400000, 2362.03], [1288573200000, 2394.35], [1288659600000, 2388.84], [1288746000000, 2391.23], [1289178000000, 2419.32], [1289264400000, 2434.15], [1289350800000, 2421.7], [1289437200000, 2436.95], [1289523600000, 2420.74], [1289610000000, 2420.22], [1289782800000, 2430.49], [1289869200000, 2436.24], [1289955600000, 2452.63], [1290042000000, 2502.14], [1290128400000, 2509.4], [1290387600000, 2521.59], [1290474000000, 2492.79], [1290560400000, 2499.77], [1290646800000, 2539.31], [1290733200000, 2541.65], [1290992400000, 2535.83], [1291078800000, 2548.12], [1291165200000, 2579.55], [1291251600000, 2630.43], [1291338000000, 2684.82], [1291597200000, 2706.76], [1291683600000, 2722.66], [1291770000000, 2699.41], [1291856400000, 2704.61], [1291942800000, 2720.08], [1292202000000, 2755.7], [1292288400000, 2775.37], [1292374800000, 2787.9], [1292461200000, 2782.11], [1292547600000, 2785.73], [1292806800000, 2822.49], [1292893200000, 2824.16], [1292979600000, 2831.9], [1293066000000, 2842.81], [1293152400000, 2842.59], [1293411600000, 2809.56], [1293498000000, 2811.79], [1293584400000, 2807.98], [1293670800000, 2810.86], [1293757200000, 2810.44], [1294707600000, 2916.55], [1294794000000, 2970.84], [1294880400000, 2985.02], [1294966800000, 2970.21], [1295226000000, 3013.12], [1295312400000, 3023.03], [1295398800000, 3034.26], [1295485200000, 2994.76], [1295571600000, 3030.34], [1295830800000, 3004.56], [1295917200000, 3007.85], [1296003600000, 3033.62], [1296090000000, 3054.33], [1296176400000, 3034.96], [1296435600000, 3001.76], [1296522000000, 3047.94], [1296608400000, 3085.91], [1296694800000, 3079.5], [1296781200000, 3081.59], [1297040400000, 3065.24], [1297126800000, 3057.8], [1297213200000, 3037.93], [1297299600000, 2994.59], [1297386000000, 3019.97], [1297645200000, 3066.61], [1297731600000, 3077.68], [1297818000000, 3075.74], [1297904400000, 3098.59], [1297990800000, 3110.37], [1298250000000, 3145.66], [1298336400000, 3114.48], [1298509200000, 3101.39], [1298595600000, 3140.65], [1298854800000, 3181.54], [1298941200000, 3187.78], [1299027600000, 3160.24], [1299114000000, 3185.79], [1299200400000, 3174.66], [1299286800000, 3178.22], [1299632400000, 3205.61], [1299718800000, 3142.39], [1299805200000, 3093.05], [1300064400000, 3095.52], [1300150800000, 2986.98], [1300237200000, 3010.72], [1300323600000, 3017.64], [1300410000000, 3040.04], [1300669200000, 3047.59], [1300755600000, 3023.41], [1300842000000, 3038.04], [1300928400000, 3068.87], [1301014800000, 3083.17], [1301270400000, 3087.51], [1301356800000, 3067.37], [1301443200000, 3098.34], [1301529600000, 3113.9], [1301616000000, 3141.69], [1301875200000, 3174.5], [1301961600000, 3172.26], [1302048000000, 3188.25], [1302134400000, 3176.8], [1302220800000, 3191.89], [1302480000000, 3185.84], [1302566400000, 3127.59], [1302652800000, 3108.23], [1302739200000, 3095.78], [1302825600000, 3089.41], [1303084800000, 3015.84], [1303171200000, 2981.92], [1303257600000, 3033.67], [1303344000000, 3053.12], [1303430400000, 3054.46], [1303689600000, 3063.89], [1303776000000, 3014.28], [1303862400000, 3014.37], [1303948800000, 3007.57], [1304035200000, 2967.66], [1304380800000, 2945.87], [1304467200000, 2901.66], [1304553600000, 2855.25], [1304640000000, 2850.45], [1304985600000, 2878.71], [1305072000000, 2866.19], [1305158400000, 2802.41], [1305244800000, 2802.41], [1305417600000, 2790.78], [1305504000000, 2790.78], [1305590400000, 2802.58], [1305676800000, 2805.54], [1305763200000, 2819.33], [1305849600000, 2795.36], [1306022400000, 2720.91], [1306108800000, 2720.91], [1306195200000, 2738.45], [1306281600000, 2742.91], [1306368000000, 2759.38], [1306454400000, 2774], [1306713600000, 2801.78], [1306800000000, 2829.22], [1306886400000, 2818.64], [1306972800000, 2799.42], [1307059200000, 2806.33], [1307318400000, 2790.76], [1307404800000, 2818.34], [1307491200000, 2836.65], [1307577600000, 2857.04], [1307664000000, 2874.5], [1308009600000, 2879.79], [1308096000000, 2905.71], [1308182400000, 2858.4], [1308268800000, 2849.95], [1308528000000, 2822.09], [1308614400000, 2846.21], [1308700800000, 2845.19], [1308787200000, 2815.21], [1308873600000, 2831.43], [1309132800000, 2814.01], [1309219200000, 2825.49], [1309305600000, 2852.74], [1309392000000, 2869.25], [1309478400000, 2909.79], [1309737600000, 2924.97], [1309824000000, 2926.85], [1309910400000, 2918.67], [1309996800000, 2961.3], [1310083200000, 2967.96], [1310342400000, 2930.53], [1310428800000, 2910.43], [1310515200000, 2927.7], [1310601600000, 2943.07], [1310688000000, 2947.03], [1310947200000, 2943.98], [1311033600000, 2925.17], [1311120000000, 2938.49], [1311206400000, 2941.49], [1311292800000, 2969.48], [1311552000000, 2955.88], [1311638400000, 2970.93], [1311724800000, 2974.8], [1311811200000, 2964.83], [1311897600000, 2959.33], [1312156800000, 2984.21], [1312243200000, 2951.08], [1312329600000, 2908.34], [1312416000000, 2840.94], [1312502400000, 2689.22], [1312761600000, 2599.58], [1312848000000, 2449.5], [1312934400000, 2534.46], [1313020800000, 2435.75], [1313107200000, 2509.19], [1313366400000, 2617.46], [1313452800000, 2607.63], [1313539200000, 2648.05], [1313625600000, 2615.57], [1313712000000, 2531.74], [1313971200000, 2553.75], [1314057600000, 2548.08], [1314144000000, 2538.26], [1314230400000, 2543.95], [1314316800000, 2515.13], [1314576000000, 2603.59], [1314662400000, 2605.23], [1314748800000, 2637.56], [1314835200000, 2630.24], [1314921600000, 2610.72], [1315180800000, 2579.43], [1315267200000, 2579.33], [1315353600000, 2621.89], [1315440000000, 2626.82], [1315526400000, 2598.39], [1315785600000, 2513.64], [1315872000000, 2525.82], [1315958400000, 2527.06], [1316044800000, 2546.5], [1316131200000, 2517.3], [1316390400000, 2486.41], [1316476800000, 2518.97], [1316563200000, 2531.8], [1316649600000, 2408.69], [1316736000000, 2247.31], [1316995200000, 2223.62], [1317081600000, 2291.87], [1317168000000, 2272.35], [1317254400000, 2279.69], [1317340800000, 2257.6], [1317600000000, 2204.21], [1317686400000, 2127.62], [1317772800000, 2097.34], [1317859200000, 2132.02]]
```

It has following structure:

```
[Date, price]
```

How can I convert all milliseconds to normal date (**DD/MM/YYYY**) inside the list?

Comment: Do you know the start date from which the ms are offset?

Comment: This list starts with 11/08/2007. But I have about 75 lists. The fist one starts in 1998 and the last one in 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like milliseconds since the epoch. You can use the Python datetime library.

```
import datetime
def timestamp(ms):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms / 1000.0).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
def use_timestamps(lst):
    return [[timestamp(ms), price] for ms, price in lst]
```

Here is the output using the list you provided:

https://pastebin.com/zJx94EpQ

Comment: Hi, Colin. Thanks for your answer. I'm really new on python and couldn't do the same. How can I figure it out to works all together? Could you please help me with that? There is my code: 
`import datetime

list = [[ 1194570000000, 1806.22 ], ..., [ 1510189200000, 6758.09 ]]

def timestamp(ms):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ms / 1000.0).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
def use_timestamps(list):
    return [[timestamp(ms), price] for ms, price in list]

print(list)`